# How do I filter out items on DnDBeyond that have no cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, dnd-beyond

I'm trying to filter [equipment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment) items on DnDBeyond so that only items whose value is between 1 cp and 1 gp is shown.

The problem is that this is giving me a lot of items that have zero cost. I tried the entering the following values for the minimum cost but none are valid:

- 1 cp
- 1 copper
- .01

I can't find any sort of key that helps with this. Is there a way to filter out items without a cost and what is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the [Equipment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment) page of DnDBeyond I set the minimum cost to 0 and the maximum cost to 1, then I select the descending order for showing the filtered list. In this way you can ignore all the items after the first with 0 cost.